# Access image in my Android Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, file-listing

I am working on an Android app. It has corresponding spec/test application. As part of some of my tests, I need to pick up an image from my assets folder and calculate SHA-1 for it. 
I can calculate SHA, as long as I can pick the image. Since the tests run on emulator; I am not sure how to pick the image in my test.

Does anyone have any idea, how I can go about it. With and without AssetManager maybe? Any ideas will be helpful.

Cheers
-Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by extending `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, then in the setup getting a reference to the activity and finally getting the `AssetManager`.

```
    public class Sha1Test
        extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {
        private AssetManager m_assetManager;
        public Sha1Test() {
            super("com.example.test", MyActivity.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            MyActivity activity = this.getActivity();
            m_assetManager = activity.getAssets();
        }

        @Override
        public void testSomething() throws Exception {
            InputStream stream = m_assetManager.open("myimage.png");
        }
    }
```

You'll need to run this on the emulator as an Android Unit Test, since it depends on the main activity to load the assets.